# StatsD displaying "go_gc_duration" metrics but not the airflow metrics

Tags: airflow, statsd

We have installed statsD exporter by following steps..

```
pip install 'apache-airflow[statsd]'
```

Added below config details

```
statsd_on = True
statsd_host = localhost
statsd_port = 8125
statsd_prefix = airflow
```

And then downloaded the below zip file

```
https://github.com/prometheus/statsd_exporter/releases/download/v0.21.0/statsd_exporter-0.21.0.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

And then executed the below command

```
./statsd_exporter --statsd.listen-udp localhost:8125 &
```

statsd metrics is started but it is showing the "go_gc_duration" stats like below but airflow stats are not being displayed.

```
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0"} 1.1717e-05
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.25"} 1.5126e-05
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.5"} 1.9535e-05
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.75"} 4.3568e-05
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="1"} 0.000384508
go_gc_duration_seconds_sum 669.380082897
go_gc_duration_seconds_count 8.186899e+06
```

but expected metrics should be as below

```
# HELP airflow_collect_dags Metric autogenerated by statsd_exporter.
# TYPE airflow_collect_dags gauge
airflow_collect_dags 50.056391
# HELP airflow_dag_loading_duration_example_bash_operator Metric 
autogenerated by statsd_exporter.
# TYPE airflow_dag_loading_duration_example_bash_operator summary
airflow_dag_loading_duration_example_bash_operator{quantile="0.5"} 1.108e-06
airflow_dag_loading_duration_example_bash_operator{quantile="0.9"} 4.942e-06
```

is there something we have to do changes or missed, pls any suggestions

Comment: @Jan Garaj any suggestions pls

Comment: Can any one pls help with any suggestion

Comment: @Can any one pls help with any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Actually or not, by reference https://quay.io/repository/prometheus/statsd-exporter

./statsd_exporter --statsd.listen-udp localhost:8125 --log.level debug

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Same thing was happening to me. In the `airflow.cfg` there is another option called `statsd_allow_list = airflow`: I deleted it, restarted AF and it's working